# Hibernate Interceptor - New session required?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

We're having a `SessionFactory` scoped Hibernate `Interceptor` that listens to `flushOnDirty` and `onSave` events. Whenever a certain object is updated/merged or saved, we're updated or saving other entities which are possibly not loaded in the session and are not directly linked to the entity to be updated or saved.

I did some investigation on the implementation requirements of a Hibernate Interceptor and came to the following conclusions:

- A `SessionFactory` scoped interceptor must be thread safe
- An `Interceptor` must follow the `Serializable` specifications
- I read some comment of someone claiming that when you want to manage objects in your interceptor, you need to create a extra session for that.

My confusion is about the 3th item:

1. Is it really required to create an extra Session and why?
2. Do I also need to create a separate Transaction for this?

Can someone enlighten me on this?